# Symfony 3 Autoload data from database

Tags: php, database, symfony, autoload

I worked on a symfony 3 project that an ex-colleague set up. 
I'm beginner with Symfony.

I don't know how to autoload data (parameters) from database to set in php constants

The app begin in this file : /web/app_matnat_dev.php

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;


require_once 'access_control.inc.php';

ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", "1");

/**
 * @var Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader $loader
 */

$loader = require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';

Debug::enable();

$kernel = new AppKernel($_SERVER['SFENV'], true);

$kernel->loadClassCache();

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();

try {
    $response = $kernel->handle($request);

    $response->send();
    $kernel->terminate($request, $response);

} catch (Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

It includes /app/autoload.php :

```
<?php

use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;
use Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader;

/**
 * @var ClassLoader $loader
 */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader([$loader, 'loadClass']);

/* Ensemble de fonctions dont j'ai besoin */
require_once __DIR__.'/../src/RecupBundle/env.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/../src/RecupBundle/autoload_orm.php';
//require_once __DIR__.'/../src/RecupBundle/constants.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/../src/RecupBundle/functions.php';

return $loader;
```

That's here i'd like (i think i can) to load from database my parameters and after include others parameters

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../src/RecupBundle/constants.php';
```

i call a method in first lines in this file

```
// database parameters to constants
use function RecupBundle\ORM\param;
RecupBundle\ORM\param()->load();
```

But i've this error

```
Notice: Undefined index: db_link in /src/RecupBundle/ORM/db_query.php on line 44
```

Because db_link is only defined in /web/app_matnat_dev.php when i do that `$response = $kernel->handle($request);`

I need help :)

Thanks

Comment: You can add database configuration in config.yml .

Comment: __Never read__ symfony manuals.

Comment: i've read symfony manuals, but i don't find answer to my question

Comment: @CaptainPlanet 

in config.yml, i've

`parameters:
    database_name: XXXXX
    database_host: XXXXX
    database_port: XXXXX
    database_user: XXXXX
    database_password: XXXXX`

Comment: You can add database information into the config.yml

Comment: @CaptainPlanet Can you be more explicit?
I'v parameters ton connect, by which information and how?

Comment: Can you paste the code in/src/RecupBundle/ORM/db_query.php?

Comment: Loading database into php constant is not possible or it wont be constants. No offense but it's seems more like old school php than symfony, maybe you should start to learn the framework your working with first?

Comment: @goto i worked on a projet that other people start... it doesn't respect exactly the  "rules".... i have to do with !
The parameters come from a crm that user can modify, the parameters are used to display or not modules on a website

Comment: @CaptainPlanet i've find a solution, thanks for your help

Comment: How exactly is `$db_link` defined? Why not load it from the DI container?

Comment: @nico $db_link is defined just after database connect

`protected function connect()
{
 $this->_link = mysqli_connect('p:'.$this->getParameter('database_host'), $this->getParameter('database_user'), $this->getParameter('database_password'), $this->getParameter('database_name'));
 mysqli_query($this->_link, "SET NAMES 'utf8';");
 $GLOBALS['db_link'] = $this->_link; 
 param()->load();
}`

Comment: Please don't put code in the comment section, and don't use globals if you use Symfony already

Comment: @NicoHaase thanks for your advice... the project is like that... i try to rebase it !

Answer (score -1):

I've found a trick: I do  request just after the connexion to the database. 
So, I can define the constants used everywhere in the project.